# Make a circled number with 2 different pattern for each half?

Tags: graphics, circles

[image]

How do I make a circled number like the drawn one: half solid line, half dotted line, with different colors?

Also, I'm hoping to use it in plain text (not tikzpicture) like:

```
step \circlednumber{3}{blue}{red}: blah blah
```

Comment: A tikzpicture can be used in plain text.

Comment: What you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\circlednumber[3]{\tikz[baseline=(@n.base)]{
  \node (@n) [minimum size=1.2em, inner sep=0pt] {#1};
  \path[draw=#2,semithick] (@n.north) arc (90:270:0.6em);
  \path[draw=#3,semithick, dashed] (@n.north) arc (90:-90:0.6em);
                                }}

\begin{document}
step \circlednumber{3}{blue}{red}: blah blah
\end{document}
```

[image]